# How could I've known the cast to List<> makes sense?

Tags: c#, casting

For this code snippet below, which probably won't need an explanation to the persons who can answer my question:

```
protected readonly List<TEntity> Records; //Within the class declared.

protected virtual void ReadFile()
{
  //So the file exists, is not null and not whitespace only
  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(Records.GetType());
  using (var reader = new StringReader(contents))
  {
    var records = (List<TEntity>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    Records.Clear();
    Records.AddRange(records);
  }
}
```

It's about the line:

```
var records = (List<TEntity>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

(1) How could I've known (deduced) that this cast was possible? I looked up that the Deserialize() methods returns the type "object". So that's can't be the hint.  (Edit: I mean during coding/design time. Not compiling afterwards for trial and error. So think goal-wise: goal = store xml data into a list<>. Is it possible through a simple cast (yes) and how could I have known in advance?).
(2) How could I've / can I deduce(d) how variable "records" would end up?   **For example**, what shouldn't make me think that only a single entry is written to the list and that single index holds all of the XML content? (as opposed to keeping a nice structure whilst writing it to the list)

The final goal of my question is to understand when such a cast is needed and **especially** *how the actual cast* makes sense. I'm wiling to put in effort in it with practice and experimentations. But I don't know how to think.

a) I"m a beginner, though learning fast i.m.o.
b) I Have read and understood implicit/explicit casting and understood that it's based on range, as opposed to data size. But those tutorials restrict to built in basic types like int, float, decimal (you name it). Now this problem domain (casting) I would like to move to a higher level.

Comment: U can check if stream can be deserialized using `XmlSerializer.CanDeserialize` function

Comment: Deserializing part is covered in the Answers below but could you share the part where the contents are written on the file so that  we can understand what assumptions were made for the snippents shared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast

```
 var records = (List<TEntity>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

works because of

```
 new XmlSerializer(Records.GetType());
```

The cast from object to anything will always compile but yield a runtime exception when the types don't match.

The serializer knows about the root type from its constructor and will create a result of that type. If the XML  doesn't match that, it will throw an error. You cannot deserialze a single TEntity with this, only a List<> with 0 or more elements.

You can verify it easily:

```
object temp = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
// print or inspect temp.GetType() here
var records = (List<TEntity>)temp;
```

Note that if XmlSerialzier had been designed as a generic type then the cast would not have been necessary:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializerGeneric<List<TEntity>>();
var records = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

But it wasn't, it uses the older way of 'dynamic typing' through the System.Object class.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much obvious if instead of this

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(Records.GetType());
```

you used this

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TEntity>));
```

The rule is simple. What ever **type** you pass to the `XmlSerializer` constructor, you can safely cast the `Deserialize` result to that **type**.

The cast is needed because `XmlSerializer` (as well as `Enum` and many other framework classes) exists from a long time before the generics were added, so returning an `object` is the only choice it had. And it must remain this way because of backward compatibility (to not break the existing code you have written).

Comment: I don't understand. Typeof would pass only TEntity to the XmlSerializer constructor. It won't give a hint that we're dealing with a List<>. And why should it, because passing that type to the constructor doesn't mean we MUST or SHALL store results later in a List<>.

Comment: No, `typeof()` will see and respect that `List<>`. It's not at liberty to ignore that.

Comment: @Valmont the documentation for the serializer indicates that the type passed in the constructor will be what the serializer constructs.

Comment: @Valmont There is a big difference if I pass `typeof(TEntity)` vs `typeof(List<TEntity>)`. The former indicates that the result will be a single object of type `TEntity` while the later - `List<TEntity>` (to be read - object of type list of TEntity objects)

Comment: @all in this subthread: I see now. Hence the reason that "typeof()" would have been clearer! I totally get this part now! I'm currently writing a mock to test all this, but it makes increasingly more sense to me!

Answer (score 1):

> How could I've known (deduced) that this cast was possible?

One way is to use the debugger.  Put a breakpoint on the `Records.Clear();` line just after `records` is set.  Then in either the Watch window or the Locals window, take a look at the type of the `records` variable.  It might say something like this:

```
object { List<TEntity> }
```

`records` is a `List<TEntity>` but it's being passed as an object because the call to `serializer.Deserialize(reader)` returns an object.  And if you didn't declare an implicit conversion from object to `List<TEntity>`, you have to use an explicit conversion.

*I recommend against implicit conversions for all but the most obvious cases.*

Answer (score 1):

> (1) How could I've known (deduced) that this cast was possible?

It all began here,

```
protected readonly List<TEntity> Records;
```

You don't have to deduce but you already know you are reading file contents from a file which has some XML with some sort of structure and since you are using a list you know upfront that there are going to be mulitple list items

> I looked up that the `Deserialize()` methods returns the type
>   "object". So that's can't be the hint.

object class is not used directly (So basically that is a hint that you have to cast) and it must be casted to some type (in this case `List<TEntity>`) before it could be used.

> (2) How could I've / can I deduce(d) how variable "records" would end
>   up?

Lets say I want to create list of persons, I would know I would keep some structure for example,

I have following XML

```
<persons>
<person>
<name>Chuck Norris</name>
<age>137</age>
</person>
<person>
<name>Donald Trump</name>
<age>19</age>
</person>
<persons>
```

You know you want to get the records of person your list would be declare like this, `List<Person>`. You know Deserialize() method returns object and you would want to read persons data, you would cast that object into `List<Person>`. So basically what I am trying to say is that both the question you asked are based on the assumption and choices made at the design time of you application.